# Disable contextual tabs MS Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, ribbon

Is it possible to disable contextual tabs in MS Word using CustomUI xml? 
I added the following to customui XML but without any effect

```
 <mso:contextualTabs>
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetSmartArtTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetChartTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetTextBoxTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetDrawingTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetDrawingToolsClassic" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetWordArtTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetDiagramTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetOrganizationChartTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetPictureTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetPictureToolsClassic" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetTableTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetHeaderAndFooterTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetEquationTools" visible="false" />
  <mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetInkTools" visible="false" />
</mso:contextualTabs>
```

Comment: Try hiding the tabs themselves.

Comment: Tried this. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to use the `getVisible` property. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
<mso:tabSet idMso="TabSetSmartArtTools" getVisible="false" />
```

Or try to **start from scratch**. See [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/hidevisible.htm)